# How to change Zen Grid System

Tags: theming

Zen is a great theme and comes by 3 columns gris as default and even when i read the documentation i don't know how to change the grid system to 2 columns 30%- 70% for ex..
Can you help me please.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a support request to a third-party project hosted on drupal.org or elsewhere. Please submit it to the project's issue queue instead, providing the steps to reproduce. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$zen-column-count: 10;

.container {
 @include zen-grid-container;
} 
.column1 {
 @include zen-grid-item(3, 1);
}
.column2 {
 @include zen-grid-item(7, 4);
}
```

You include 10 columns, and use 3 for 30% and 7 for 70%. Reason being that columns are of equal width and if you want to implement two unequal columns you have to use multiples of a common denominator.

Comment: ok wait,i will test it and give you a feedback

Comment: But add this css to what?

Comment: `<div class="container">
<div class="column1">
some content
</div>
<div class="column2">
some content
</div>
</div>`

Comment: i don't understand,do i have to add this css to my template.php or style.css or what?

Comment: Technically this is SCSS and you edit scss files. It has to be pre-processed by SASS. You have to install Ruby, some requirements, SASS and Compass gems. You install Zen theme, create Zen subtheme. You use bundler to install gem dependencies (Zen Grids etc). When that is all done, you issue your compass watch command. Compass will then watch your scss folder that is in the zen sub theme for changes. You then edit the scss files and it generates css. Search for the Complete Guide To Omega 4 on youtube as it explains a lot of the installation. And search for how to install compass and SASS.

Comment: OK that's great, but i really need a step-by-step tuto to help me,